# Working with hierarchy (tree) in R

Tags: r, tree, hierarchy, igraph

This is a general question about options of handling tree-like (hierarchy) data in R, as well as feasibility of igraph package for the task in hand.

Multiple hierarchies are stored in a relational table in a structure like:

```
Name ID PID Start Date  End Date
A    1      12/31/14    
B    2  1   12/31/14    
C    3  1   12/31/14    1/31/15
D    4  2   12/31/14    
Z    5      6/30/14 
Y    6  5   6/30/14     12/31/14
X    7  6   7/31/14      9/30/14
W    8  5   7/31/14
```

The structure of each hierarchy changes over time as indicated by "Start Date" and "End Date". In other words, the structure could potentially be different on any given day.

My objective at this point is to find an efficient and easy way of constructing an R-object from that data, and establish a framework for further manipulation/transformation of these hierarchies. The initial research tells me that the igraph package could be a good answer. One thing I'm not certain is the time dimension aspect (looks like the proper name is a "temporal graph").

Here are some of the common tasks I'm looking to do:

1. Get composition of any hierarchy on any given day.
2. Identify changes between two dates in any node (hierarchy delta).
3. While each hierarchy is a tree with a single root (directed tree), there is a requirement to establish logic relationship between nodes of two hierarchies (a hierarchy pair).
4. Assign attributes to nodes and search graph by them.
5. Export hierarchy in a flat view like:

`Date   Level1  Level2  Level3
12/31/14    A   B       D
12/31/14    A   C
12/31/14    Z   Y
12/31/14    Z   W
2/1/15      A   B       D
2/1/15      Z   W`

I was able to create a graph object from the parent-child data (without time dimension), but could not figure out how to transform it into that flat structure.

Any suggestions and ideas are super welcome!